# Android Studio Kotlin エラー　Unsolved Reference

Tags: android, kotlin

途中まで、ちゃんと動いていたのですが、いきなり、Unsolved Referenceのエラーが出てしまいました。6個くらいのActivityファイルがあるのですが、全部のファイルのR.layout.hogehoge_activityのところのRで赤くなってエラーが出ます。

Android Studioを初めて2週間の初心者です。

環境は
API28 revision 6
emulator-5554 Android 9
Android Studio 3.1.4
SDK tools 26.1.1
↑開発言語　Kotlin

たくさんアクティビティファイルがありますので、エラー内容がわかるであろう、MainActivityとbuild.gradleと、Manifestファイル、を書きました。

インターネットで調べたのですが、有益な情報が見つかりませんでしたので、詳しい方、お願い済ます。

エラー内容を記します。

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

1つめのファイル　MainActivity

```
package com.example.yusuke.mysql02

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import com.example.yusuke.mysql02.Grobal.grobalusername
import com.example.yusuke.mysql02.R.id.username
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
//import com.example.yusuke.mysql02.Grobal.num
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONObject


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    val jsonobj = JSONObject()

    fun nextactivity(v:View){

        jsonobj.put("username",username.text)
        jsonobj.put("password",password.text)

       val URL = "http://www.example.com/registeractivity.php"
       val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)


        val req = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,jsonobj,
                Response.Listener{
            response ->

                    Grobal.grobalexsist = response.toString()

                },Response.ErrorListener {
           Grobal.grobalexsist = "0"
        })

        que.add(req)


        var nametext : String = username.getText().toString()
        var passtext : String = password.getText().toString()

        Grobal.grobalusername = nametext
        Grobal.grobalpassword = passtext

        val intent = Intent(this,RegisteredActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    fun loginactivity(v: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

2つ目のファイル　build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yusuke.mysql02"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

}
```

3つ目のファイル　Manifestファイル

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yusuke.mysql02">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisteredActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".choseuserActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".addfriend" />
        <activity android:name=".Message"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/145838

Answer (score 0):

Unsolved Reference で R が赤いなら、ただ単に R の候補が複数あるだけなのでは？
R をもっと詳しく指定するか、import してみてはどうでしょうか。
import com.example.yusuke.mysql02.R とか…。